# Assigning a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am having trouble creating a numpy array. I have a numpy array with some shape and I am trying to create a new array with the shape (2, other_array_shape). Something like:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((100, 100))
y = np.zeros((2, i for i in x.shape))
```

However, this comes back with invalid syntax error. Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to concatenate two tuples:

```
>>> arr = np.zeros((2,) +  x.shape)
>>> arr.shape
(2, 100, 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append the tuple:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((100, 100))
y = np.zeros((2,) + x.shape)
```